# Docker container status sync with spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I pack my spring boot apps in Docker containers and deploy to Kubernettes. I want the container status to be "up" only when the spring boot application is up, by default the container is "up" and spring boot app is still starting.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a Health Check Endpoint, so Kubernetes (but also locally Docker) can test if your application is ready or not.

Consider using Spring Actuator and enable the health endpoint. You can find the information here at this link: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-actuator/

Once you have the Actuator active, you can configure in your Kubernetes Deployment YAML [the startup-, readiness- and livenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) and the Docker [HEALTHCHECK](https://HEALTHCHECK) keyword

The startupProbe is useful for slow starting applications, so you might want to configure `periodSeconds` and `failureThreshold` to high values, so that the application will be declared "failed" if the `failureThreshold*periodSeconds` is passed, but if it's started correctly, then will liveness and readiness Probes activated

Comment: yeah, I have the health check, readiness and liveness probe. the problem is that i have to set a big initial delay as the health check fails until the spring app is up, and container is running, that's the main reason I would like docker to have the up state once the app is running, so i won't need the liveness probe delay